# Two different create folder options in create menu

Tags: alfresco-share

I want to create Two different create folder options in alfresco menu create menu with my custom types.

can anyone help me, how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Alfresco Version
5.0.d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In share-config-custom.xml type following:

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary">
        <create-content>
            <content id="newFOlderId" mimetype="text/plain" label="newLabel" itemid="cm:folder" icon=""/>
        </create-content>
    </config>
```

itemid - use your custom type

Comment: Thanks Diachenko, Its working fine.  But i got one more challenge that, this custom create folder option is available for all sites and all users. So can i show that option only for specific site or specific user or inside specific type of folders only.  Can you please help me with this?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Please tell me how can i show that create folder option for specific site only.   i think i need to write the evaluator. but im not getting exact code for it.  can you please help me with this???

Comment: For this you need change permissionDefinitions.xml.
See this guide:
http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/concepts/secur-permissions.html

Comment: It will set needed permissions for your action. But action menu will not disappear. You are right. You should create evaluator.

See following guide:
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dev-extensions-share-evaluators.html

Comment: Hi Diachenko, I have done with it, its working fine. but now i want to show that create menu only inside Document Library. Means if i will Enter into the sub folders of Document Library, then i want to hide Create and upload option as well. Can you please suggest the way, how can i do this.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create any evaluators?

Comment: No, i haven't created any evaluator. I am using predefined evaluator. i.e site.module.evaluator

Comment: Now you need to create new evaluator with current folder validation.

Comment: can you help me how can i create evaluator for Current folder validation??   If possible, please provide code spinet and steps to implement this. As i am new in alfresco, so dont having much idea about this. so facing some issues. Thank you.